# How to access class attributes in Python which are added in later stage?

Tags: xcode, python-2.7

```
 class Employee:
 'Common base class for all employees'
  empCount = 0

 def __init__(self, name, salary):
   self.name = name
    self.salary = salary
  Employee.empCount += 1

def displayCount(self):
  print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount

def displayEmployee(self):
   print "Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary

"This would create first object of Employee class"
   emp1 = Employee("Zara", 2000)
 "This would create second object of Employee class"
  emp2 = Employee("Manni", 5000)
  emp1.displayEmployee()
  emp2.displayEmployee()
  print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount
```

If I add age attribute later on as emp1.age = 7  . Then how can I access it?

I tried- print"     age of employee1:%d" %d self.age
But its giving error .

Comment: it should work but check your question: indentation is horrible, and "its giving error" isn't very useful to us.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting ? 
The external variable you have created wont be in the class namespace but it's present in instance namespace. 
so you can't fetch it with class name, try printing with `object.__dict__` you will find the variable.